# vue computed ant watch won't trigger on nested property changes

Tags: vue.js

Computed method triggers if one of the main property,which is declared inside the data(){}

But won't trigger on nested property changes. even I used watch deep.

```js
myApp.component("editfeemodal", {
    props: ['feedetail'],
    data() {
        return {
        }
    },   
    computed: {
        validated: function () {
            try {
                if (this.feedetail.glCode === null || this.feedetail.glCode === "" || typeof this.feedetail.glCode == 'undefined')
                    return false;
                return true;

            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        feedetail: {
            handler(newValue, oldValue) {
                this.validFee = false;
            },
            deep: true
        },
    },
    methods: {
        "saveFeeDetails": function () {}
    },
    template:'
     <select v-model="feedetail.glCode" class="form-select" v-bind:class="[feedetail.glCode=='' ?'is-invalid':'']" id="inputGroupSelectGLCode" >
        <option value="" selected>Choose...</option>
        <option value="1000">1000</option>
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
        <option value="3000">3000</option>
       </select>
    '
    })
```

Does any one knows why and how to sort this out,please?

Regards

Comment: That's because the reference to the object is staying the same, even though the value is changing.

Comment: Can you also share your `watch` code, and specify if Vue 2 or Vue 3, and I will write you a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing objects, you are actually comparing a reference to that object, hence modifying a value within it will not trigger the watch event.

You will need to use a "deep watch" to target the specific value that will be changing.

```js
watch: {
    searchText: {
        handle(newValue, oldValue) {
            this.result = newValue.text
        },
        deep: true
    }
}
```

Or, more shortly:

```js
watch: {
    'searchText.text': function(newValue, oldValue) {
        this.resule = newValue
    }
}
```

For a more complete example, here's a [working CodeSandbox project](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-watchers-so-answer-for-aliazra-4vq3iw?file=/src/components/EditFeeModal.vue) based on your code.

From the Vue docs: [`vm.$watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/?redirect=true#vm-watch)

> When mutating (rather than replacing) an Object or an Array, the old value will be the same as new value because they reference the same Object/Array. Vue doesn’t keep a copy of the pre-mutate value.

Comment: Hi Lissy93, thank you for help. But still not working. I have edited my question with actual code and not sure why watch is not triggered.

Comment: Here's a working example for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-watchers-so-answer-for-aliazra-4vq3iw?file=/src/components/EditFeeModal.vue

Answer (score 1):

Watch is shallow by default, what you need is deep watch
, please refer to https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers

```
watch:{
    searchText: {
      deep: true,
      handle() {
        return this.searchText.id;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Luis. I tried above code but Computed doesn't use deep. compiler shows error.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, it should be  `watch` instead of `computed`, I just copied and pasted the code from your example and totally forgot to change it to `watch`. Sorry for that.